# "Typically, the subject has the agent role" -- how frequent is this, really?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-subject, quantitative-linguistics, agentivity, active

In introductory books or reference works, this kind of statement recurs over and over: "In the active voice, the subject is *typically* an agent". However, it is obvious that many verbs have non-agentive subjects even in the active voice, like "get, know, stand, lie, hang, contain, resemble" ...etc. So how can you be so sure that agent is "typical" here? (Note: we are dealing with a statement on the active voice of verbs; I am not talking about agency being cognitively prominent in the perception of events etc).

You would think that the best way of judging this would be frequency (of occurrences, or of types in the vocabulary). So – can anybody direct me to serious work that has measured the actual textual frequency of agentive vs. non-agentive subjects? Or at least the number of agentive verbs in the lexicon vs. non-agentive verbs?

Comment: It's nonsensical to say that they might have forgotten when they literally used a word that means commonly but not exclusively. Remove that part from the question and then someone might be able to bring some actual stats.

Comment: @curiousdannii ‘Typically’ does not mean “commonly, but not exclusively” – that would be ‘often’. ‘Typically’ means “**most** commonly, but not exclusively”. That is not a trivial distinction. Stats are absolutely relevant to that phrasing. If only 45% of subjects in active-voice constructions actually correspond to agents, it would be false to state that they are typically agents. To wit, none of the subjects in this comment are actual agents.

Comment: @Janus:  Yes, and I think "typically" is used here with something like "prototype theory" in the back of one's mind. That means, it comes next to what would be "defining feature" in a model other than prototype theory. (But has it ever been established whether "active voice" is organised in terms of a prototype category?).

Comment: "In introductory books or reference works, you always see this kind of statement: "In the active voice, the **subject** is typically an agent". I keep wondering what people mean when they say "typically" - does it mean they simply forgot about **a whole lot of other verbs**, like "get, know, stand, lie, hang, contain, resemble" ...etc" **You move from the word subject to th word verb in a non-sequitur way. Why is that??

Comment: Because it is about the active voice. The subject ist determined by the meaning of the verb, no rearrangements.

Comment: If false, perhaps this is just sloppy wording for the distinct concept “typically, an agent is expressed as a subject”.

Comment: Alternatively, such statements may be implictly scoped to discussions of transitive verb uses, where the syntactic role of subject contrasts with a distinct syntactic role of object. It isn't what you're asking for, but "Thematic role properties of subjects and objects", Edward Kako,  2005 seems to be largely involved with studying sentences in a transitive frame.

Comment: Sometimes it is very hard to tell, whether it is implicitly restricted to transitive "action" or not, e.g. the text in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Active_voice  -- Thanks for the reference.